# Using Linq to pull from IEnumerable<XElement> and store in data table

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-xml, ienumerable

I have a datatable that looks like the following

```
public static DataTable SetColumnHeaders(DataTable KeyDataTable)
{
    KeyDataTable.Columns.Add("First_Name", typeof(string));
    KeyDataTable.Columns.Add("Last_Name", typeof(string));
    KeyDataTable.Columns.Add("Address1", typeof(string));
    KeyDataTable.Columns.Add("Address2", typeof(bool));
    KeyDataTable.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
    KeyDataTable.Columns.Add("State", typeof(bool));
    KeyDataTable.Columns.Add("Zip", typeof(string));
    KeyDataTable.Columns.Add("Zip4", typeof(bool));
    KeyDataTable.Columns.Add("Match_File", typeof(bool));
    return KeyDataTable;
}
```

My goal is to read information in from an xml and store that specific data into my datatable. I have a separate xml file for each "Quote" so I will be appending a new row to the datatable. The part of the xml I am concerned with is as follows:

```
    '- <ACORD>
    - <SignonRq>
    - <SignonPswd>
    - <CustId>
      <SPName>com.agencyport</SPName> 
      </CustId>
    - <CustPswd>
      <EncryptionTypeCd>NONE</EncryptionTypeCd> 
      <Pswd>default</Pswd> 
      </CustPswd>
      </SignonPswd>
      <ClientDt>2006-04-04T15:44:00</ClientDt> 
      <CustLangPref>en-US</CustLangPref> 
    - <ClientApp>
      <Org>Applied Systems</Org> 
      <Name>WinTam</Name> 
      <Version>7.1.0</Version> 
      </ClientApp>
      </SignonRq>
    - <InsuranceSvcRq>
      <RqUID>81913CB5-3EAB-F158-EE24-5910F9BE9C26</RqUID> 
    - <PersAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq>
      <RqUID>7B010E52-44F2-487A-521B-9D1E3500C23D</RqUID> 
    - <Producer id="AB4E95FF02FA91FAA4D7A2D96B59D8866A">
    - <ProducerInfo id="AF04551B40F1439BCCC77CA3A21165FFAA">
      <ContractNumber id="AD2178F32385016684F33F848830CAA18A">AP</ContractNumber> 
      </ProducerInfo>
      </Producer>

<InsuredOrPrincipal id="A498E0A503206279EE434988B68472974A">
                <GeneralPartyInfo id="A4F0BBE53B311050FD0552BB41090A523A">
                    <NameInfo id="AFBDE1032EEEA0821374C7C9428B0B44CA">
                        <PersonName id="A883A5BFD8FA8E71F52780B1E678AD64AA">
                            <Surname id="A40A625346687D257582BF6499710839BA">TEST</Surname>
                            <GivenName id="A021FD886DAAF628327F542786B6CD9B5A">TEST</GivenName>
                            <OtherGivenName id="A06DB1E21AF9BD37420B5C39E6562C78AA">TEST</OtherGivenName>
                        </PersonName>
                        <TaxIdentity id="ABC2680C3B21A161E54BCDBA78DFCCE77A">
                            <TaxIdTypeCd id="A050BE41EE9F2B1C713E934B1D6D2B31BA">SSN</TaxIdTypeCd>
                        </TaxIdentity>
                    </NameInfo>
                    <Addr id="A0C5DF11BD2CF70669AE368F685DAD141A">
                        <AddrTypeCd id="A82658A7F5CEB14239A4023874F594FC9A">MailingAddress</AddrTypeCd>
                        <Addr1 id="A0DC5C008818A7559527AD40AB1E0D8E0A">100 MAIN ST</Addr1>
                        <City id="A7DBC851540752437C649745A63508198A">Howell</City>
                        <StateProvCd id="ACDF462092E91668AD7996C662ACC1622A">MI</StateProvCd>
                        <PostalCode id="A45C6341382A3314D1EC79FEF20FE9D82A">48843</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCd id="AD69C7B00BB7F210588E016FF281675F6A">Livingston</CountryCd>
                    </Addr>
                    <Communications id="AFC53B2B003342664BE4635C38C7C6C45A">
                        <PhoneInfo id="AE5497FDB30717F033E8DFA47B3A36142A">
                            <PhoneTypeCd id="AF8662F35A8F1FD3DD993CECB53EB2FCAA">Phone</PhoneTypeCd>
                            <CommunicationUseCd id="ADA98E4A9B820C002189B1124F071D462A">Home</CommunicationUseCd>
                            <PhoneNumber id="A7F0F2A55F636FB6DCED2F6815271B352A">313-272-6576</PhoneNumber>
                        </PhoneInfo>
                    </Communications>
                </GeneralPartyInfo>
                <InsuredOrPrincipalInfo id="A09004254D9A7BE38EA45B20CCD6A0EC2A">
                    <InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd id="A2B16D7C6D9CE94DB83DDC6C69BE52BDBA">Insured</InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>
                    <PersonInfo id="AE7CB4EE90C6BEBB1C79DF10415B3B8E5A">
                        <MiscParty id="A3AC37CD29B32FA46D0204601CE86F0C0A">
                            <MiscPartyInfo id="A5A9326BB8C3E68900D23F62420A06362A">
                                <MiscPartyRoleCd id="A92E022991F988677D6EF8434207DDEBBA">Employer</MiscPartyRoleCd>
                            </MiscPartyInfo>
                        </MiscParty>
                    </PersonInfo>
                </InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
            </InsuredOrPrincipal>
```

What I have come up with so far is this:

```
public static void ExportAutoToText()
{
    DirectoryInfo AutoDir = new DirectoryInfo(FilePrep.AutoDirectory);
    DataTable AutoDataTable = new DataTable();

    AutoDataTable = SetColumnHeaders(AutoDataTable); // set column headers


    foreach (FileInfo File in AutoDir.GetFiles())
    {
        DataRow fileRow = AutoDataTable.NewRow();
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(AutoDir + File.Name);

        //decide if i want to keep the file
        IEnumerable<XElement> personinfo = 
            from per in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("InsuredOrPrincipal")
            where (string)per.Element("InsuredOrPrincipalInfo")
                  .Element("InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd") == ("Insured")
            select per;

        // I then want to update the information in my datatable
        //fileRow["First_Name"] = xVal.Element("GeneralPartyInfo")
        //                                        .Element("NameInfo")
        //                                        .Element("PersonName")
        //                                        .Element("GivenName");

        //fileRow["Last_Name"] = xVal.Element("GeneralPartyInfo")
        //                                        .Element("NameInfo")
        //                                        .Element("PersonName")
        //                                        .Element("Surname");
    }
}
```

This method is inside of a Class so you can assume getting the file and everything works just fine. I just need to know the most efficient way of accessing the data from the xml file and storing it in my datatable. I'v tried looping data as follows:

```
foreach (var Xval in personinfo)
{
   //get the element info 
}
```

I just dont know enough about xml to know how to access it.Thanks again and If you need more information please let me know. 
**

Comment: Do you need to save each InsuredOrPrincipal element that is an insured or just the first you encounter?  There could be more than one. Many ACORD xml implementations will list spouses in separate InsuredOrPrincipal aggregates. This is because /InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/PersonInfo is not repeating in the ACORD schema. Sometimes, the second instance will have the role code of "Coinsured".

Comment: This is one quote. Im only interested in this section of the xml the rest is pretty much trash.

Comment: @dblood I have come up with the issue you stated above with the COinsured. How am I suppose to handle this. My updated code is below. ThankYou!!

Comment: I figured it out by doing a second loop through another class
 '            InsuredOrPrincipal[] coInsured = xmlDoc.Root
               .Descendants("InsuredOrPrincipal")
               .Select(x => new InsuredOrPrincipal(x))
               .Where(ip => ip.InsuredOrPrincipalInfo.InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd == "Coinsured")
               .ToArray();

Comment: Answered similar question, please check this [How to convert XElement object into a dataset or datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726920/1416821)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer creating objects for each node level.  It is easier to debug and test.

Using this [xml library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/).

You'd create classes for each part, like:

```
public class InsuredOrPrincipal 
{
    XElement self;
    public InsuredOrPrincipal(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public GeneralPartyInfo GeneralPartyInfo { get { return _GeneralPartyInfo ?? (_GeneralPartyInfo = new GeneralPartyInfo(self.GetElement("GeneralPartyInfo"))); } }
    GeneralPartyInfo _GeneralPartyInfo;

    public InsuredOrPrincipalInfo InsuredOrPrincipalInfo 
    { get { return _InsuredOrPrincipalInfo ?? (_InsuredOrPrincipalInfo = new InsuredOrPrincipalInfo(self.GetElement("InsuredOrPrincipalInfo"))); } }
    InsuredOrPrincipalInfo _InsuredOrPrincipalInfo;
}

public class GeneralPartyInfo
{
    XElement self;
    public GeneralPartyInfo(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public NameInfo NameInfo { get { return _NameInfo ?? (_NameInfo = new NameInfo(self.GetElement("NameInfo"))); } }
    NameInfo _NameInfo;

}

public class InsuredOrPrincipalInfo
{
    XElement self;
    public InsuredOrPrincipalInfo(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public string InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd
    {
        get { return self.Get("InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd", string.Empty); }
    }
}

public class NameInfo
{
    XElement self;
    public NameInfo(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public PersonName PersonName { get { return _PersonName ?? (_PersonName = new PersonName(self.GetElement("PersonName"))); } }
    PersonName _PersonName;
}

public class PersonName
{
    XElement self;
    public PersonName(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public string Surname 
    { 
         get { return self.Get("Surname", string.Empty); }
         set { self.Set("Surname", value, false); }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
foreach (FileInfo File in AutoDir.GetFiles())
{
    DataRow fileRow = AutoDataTable.NewRow();
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(AutoDir + File.Name);

    InsuredOrPrincipal[] insured = xmlDoc.Root
        .Descendants("InsuredOrPrincipal")
        .Select(x => new InsuredOrPrincipal(x))
        .Where(ip => ip.InsuredOrPrincipalInfo.InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd == "Insured")
        .ToArray();

    foreach(var person in insured)
    {
        string surname = person.GeneralPartyInfo.NameInfo.PersonName.Surname;
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs you can expand or shrink the number of classes and information per class as you need, but this is the way I'd go about it, as it makes more sense to me.

Tested with this code:

```
XElement test = new XElement("test");
var ip = new InsuredOrPrincipal(test);
ip.GeneralPartyInfo.NameInfo.PersonName.Surname = "Surname";
test.Save(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "insuredOrPrincipal.xml"));
```

Which gave me the expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InsuredOrPrincipal>
  <GeneralPartyInfo>
    <NameInfo>
      <PersonName>
        <Surname>Surname</Surname>
      </PersonName>
    </NameInfo>
  </GeneralPartyInfo>
</InsuredOrPrincipal>
```

Comment: InsuredOrPrincipal is a repeating element. He'll need to be able read in all InsuredOrPrincipal elements and find each one where /InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd == "Insured".

Comment: Your get elements need to be self.Elements

Your last Class 

public class PersonName
{
    XElement self;
    public PersonName(XElement self) { this.self = self; } //changed

    public string Surname 
    { 
         get { return self.Get("Surname", string.Empty); } }
         set { self.Set("Surname", value, false); }
    }
}

Comment: Also your self.gets cause errors. Linq.XElements does not have a .get or a set?

Comment: { get { return self.Get("Surname", string.Empty); } } //<< this is extra }

Comment: just thought i would let you guys know I did indeed get it working as I intended. Some of the above code has Semtex errors. and I have not got the sets to work yet. So if you have insight on how that should work it would be great!!

Comment: Semtex errors? Better call the bomb squad in to deal with those.

Comment: Syntax errors fixed, everything else works as expected.  You can see the test code I added at the end of the post.  Click the edit below the post to see what changed.

Comment: I think the issue i was having with the get is the fact that I am using 2010 and it seems you were using 2008. set { self.Element("OtherGivenName").SetValue(value); } is all i need for the set. Thanks Though

Comment: Was the confusion, that you didn't download the file from the link?

Comment: That like is not accessible from my workplace. So I was going off your inline code.

Answer (score 0):

You can bake your "isInsured" check and your selection of a person into the one query;

```
var query = from p in xmlDoc.Elements()
            where ((string)p.Element("InsuredOrPrincipalInfo")
                        .Element("InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd")) == "Insured"
            select new
            {
                Firstname = (string)p.Element("GeneralPartyInfo")
                .Element("NameInfo")
                .Element("PersonName")
                .Element("GivenName"),

                LastName = (string)p.Element("GeneralPartyInfo")
                .Element("NameInfo")
                .Element("PersonName")
                .Element("Surname"),
            };

var person = query.FirstOrDefault();
if (person != null)
{
    var fileRow = AutoDataTable.NewRow();
    fileRow["First_Name"] = person.Firstname;
    fileRow["Last_name"] = person.LastName;
}
```

This isn't super-robust in terms of handling XML in an unexpected format, but it should serve as a good starting point for you. Just fill out the anonymous object initialization with the rest of your elements, casting to the desired types.

Comment: I am trying to do this however i am getting a NULLReferanceException was unhandled on the ((string)p.Element("InsuredOrPrincipalInfo")
                        .Element("InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd")) == "Insured"

Comment: I have posted the upper portion to the xml in the original question. I would like to know how to do this several different ways if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace xmlCustomReformat
{
    class importXml
    {
        public DataTable _ComboDataTable;
        public void ExportAutoToText()
        {
            DirectoryInfo AutoDir = new DirectoryInfo(FilePrep.AutoDirectory);

            CreateDataTable(); // set column headers

           foreach (FileInfo File in AutoDir.GetFiles())
           {
               DataRow fileRow = _ComboDataTable.NewRow();
               XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(AutoDir + File.Name);

               InsuredOrPrincipal[] insured = xmlDoc.Root
                   .Descendants("InsuredOrPrincipal")
                   .Select(x => new InsuredOrPrincipal(x))
                   .Where(ip => ip.InsuredOrPrincipalInfo.InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd == "Insured")
                   .ToArray();

               foreach (var person in insured)
               {
                   fileRow["First_Name"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.NameInfo.PersonName.GivenName;
                   fileRow["Last_name"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.NameInfo.PersonName.Surname;
                   fileRow["Address1"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.Addr.Address1;
                   fileRow["City"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.Addr.City;
                   fileRow["State"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.Addr.State;
                   fileRow["Zip"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.Addr.Zip;
                   fileRow["Address2"] = " ";
                   fileRow["Zip4"] = " ";
                   fileRow["Match_File"] = File.Name.ToString();
                   _ComboDataTable.Rows.Add(fileRow);
               }
           }
        }

        public void ExportHomeToText()
        {
            DirectoryInfo HomeDir = new DirectoryInfo(FilePrep.HomeDirectory);

            foreach (FileInfo File in HomeDir.GetFiles())
            {
                DataRow fileRow = _ComboDataTable.NewRow();
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(HomeDir + File.Name);

                InsuredOrPrincipal[] insured = xmlDoc.Root
                    .Descendants("InsuredOrPrincipal")
                    .Select(x => new InsuredOrPrincipal(x))
                    .Where(ip => ip.InsuredOrPrincipalInfo.InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd == "Insured")
                    .ToArray();

                foreach (var person in insured)
                {
                    fileRow["First_Name"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.NameInfo.PersonName.GivenName;
                    fileRow["Last_name"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.NameInfo.PersonName.Surname;
                    fileRow["Address1"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.Addr.Address1;
                    fileRow["City"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.Addr.City;
                    fileRow["State"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.Addr.State;
                    fileRow["Zip"] = person.GeneralPartyInfo.Addr.Zip;
                    fileRow["Address2"] = " ";
                    fileRow["Zip4"] = " ";
                    fileRow["Match_File"] = File.Name.ToString();
                    _ComboDataTable.Rows.Add(fileRow);
                }
            }
            ExportDataTable.Write(_ComboDataTable, HomeDir.Parent.FullName.ToString());
        }

        public void CreateDataTable()
        {
            _ComboDataTable = new DataTable();

            _ComboDataTable.Columns.Add("First_Name", typeof(string));
            _ComboDataTable.Columns.Add("Last_Name", typeof(string));
            _ComboDataTable.Columns.Add("Address1", typeof(string));
            _ComboDataTable.Columns.Add("Address2", typeof(string));
            _ComboDataTable.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
            _ComboDataTable.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
            _ComboDataTable.Columns.Add("Zip", typeof(string));
            _ComboDataTable.Columns.Add("Zip4", typeof(string));
            _ComboDataTable.Columns.Add("Match_File", typeof(string));  
        }

    }
}
```

The class Comp looks like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace xmlCustomReformat
{
    public class InsuredOrPrincipal 
    {
        XElement self;
        public InsuredOrPrincipal(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

        public GeneralPartyInfo GeneralPartyInfo { get { return _GeneralPartyInfo ?? (_GeneralPartyInfo = new GeneralPartyInfo(self.Element("GeneralPartyInfo"))); } }
        GeneralPartyInfo _GeneralPartyInfo;

        public InsuredOrPrincipalInfo InsuredOrPrincipalInfo 
        { get { return _InsuredOrPrincipalInfo ?? (_InsuredOrPrincipalInfo = new InsuredOrPrincipalInfo(self.Element("InsuredOrPrincipalInfo"))); } }
        InsuredOrPrincipalInfo _InsuredOrPrincipalInfo;
    }

    public class GeneralPartyInfo
    {
        XElement self;
        public GeneralPartyInfo(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

        public NameInfo NameInfo { get { return _NameInfo ?? (_NameInfo = new NameInfo(self.Element("NameInfo"))); } }
        NameInfo _NameInfo;

        public Addr Addr { get { return _Addr ?? (_Addr = new Addr(self.Element("Addr"))); } }
        Addr _Addr;

    }

    public class InsuredOrPrincipalInfo
    {
        XElement self;
        public InsuredOrPrincipalInfo(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

        public string InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd
        {
            get { return (string)self.Element("InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd"); }
        }
    }

    public class NameInfo
    {
        XElement self;
        public NameInfo(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

        public PersonName PersonName { get { return _PersonName ?? (_PersonName = new PersonName(self.Element("PersonName"))); } }
        PersonName _PersonName;
    }

    public class Addr
    {
        XElement self;
        public Addr(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

        public string Address1
        {
            get { return (string)self.Element("Addr1"); }
        }
        public string City
        {
            get { return (string)self.Element("City"); }
        }
        public string State
        {
            get { return (string)self.Element("StateProvCd"); }
        }
        public string Zip
        {
            get { return (string)self.Element("PostalCode"); }
        }
    }

    public class PersonName
    {
        XElement self;
        public PersonName(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

        public string Surname 
        { 
             get { return (string)self.Element("Surname"); } 
        }
        public string GivenName 
        {
            get { return (string)self.Element("GivenName"); }
        }
    }
}
```

And Of course my export back to a text file for my append.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace xmlCustomReformat
{
    public static class ExportDataTable
    {
       public static void Write(DataTable dt, string filePath)
        {
            int i = 0;
            StreamWriter sw = null;

            try
            {

                sw = new StreamWriter(filePath + "\\Acord_Combined.txt", false);

                for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count-1; i++)
                {

                    sw.Write(String.Format("{0,-50}",dt.Columns[i].ColumnName));

                }
                sw.Write(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);
                sw.WriteLine();

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    object[] array = row.ItemArray;

                    for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(String.Format("{0,-50}",array[i].ToString()));
                    }
                    sw.Write(array[i].ToString());
                    sw.WriteLine();

                }

                sw.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Operation : \n" + ex.ToString(),
                                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I still need to append data back into The same xml files after I do some processing. As well as I have to depersonalize the data. So I'm assuming I just need to do sets rather than Gets. Not sure of the syntax for this process yet. If you have suggestions to improve this please feel free to leave a comment.